# Using Python Networkx and Numpy.Choice & Getting ValueError

Tags: python, python-2.7, numpy, random, networkx

Language: Python 2.x
Packages: Networkx, Numpy

My code picks a random node from my graph then does the following:

1- if it's an isolate, go back to the beginning of the while loop and pick another random node

2- if it is not an isolate, get it's neighbors

3 - if it has only 1 neighbor then the random neighbor you pick is that only neighbor

4-if it has more than one neighbor, then pick a random neighbor out of the choices available

5- that random choice, check to see if ***it*** has neighbors. Just like above.. if it has one than set the neighbor of neighbor to be that one neighbor

6-if it had more than one then pick a random neighbor of neighbor

7- connect the neighbor of my neighbor to me (the original random node)

This code HAD been working until I introduced some minor changes in another part of my program. I know all the syntax works, but I simply cannot get passed the error. Below is my code and the error.

```
while i <= self.iterations:
            node_list = nx.nodes(self.origin_network)


            random_node = numpy.random.choice(node_list)
            #print (" This random node has no neighbors:", self.origin_network.neighbors(random_node))
            if nx.is_isolate(self.origin_network, random_node) == True:
                i += 1
                print (" This random node has no neighbors:", self.origin_network.neighbors(random_node), "on turn", i)
                continue
            else:
                Neighbs = self.origin_network.neighbors(random_node)

                if len(Neighbs) == 1:
                    print ("The neighbor has no additional neighbors", "on turn", i)
                    random_neighb = Neighbs
                else:
                    random_neighb = numpy.random.choice(Neighbs) ***#This is line 108 which the error references***

                neighbs_of_neighb = self.origin_network.neighbors(random_neighb)
                if len(neighbs_of_neighb) == 1:
                    print ("This neighbor has only the original neighbor on turn", i)
                    random_NofN = neighbs_of_neighb
                    self.origin_network.add_edge(random_node, random_NofN)
                else:
                    random_NofN = numpy.random.choice(neighbs_of_neighb)
                    self.origin_network.add_edge(random_node, random_NofN)
                    print "success"
            i += 1
```

The error I receive is:

> ```
> self.triadic_method(self.origin_network , iteration, sim_number)
> ```
>
> File "D:\network.py", line 108, in triadic_method
>       random_neighb = numpy.random.choice(Neighbs)
>     File "mtrand.pyx", line 1121, in mtrand.RandomState.choice (numpy\random\mtrand\mtrand.c:12473)
>     File "mtrand.pyx", line 945, in mtrand.RandomState.randint (numpy\random\mtrand\mtrand.c:10732)
>   ValueError: low >= high

line 108 which the error references is this one:

random_neighb = numpy.random.choice(Neighbs) ***#This is line 108 which the error references***

Comment: I'm bothered by this line: `random_neighb = Neighbs` because I think you want `random_neighb` to be a node while `Neighbs` is a list (here containing a single node).  Shouldn't it be `random_neighb = Neighbs[0]`?

Comment: Wouldn't a single object be the same as a single item lists the way I had it coded?

Comment: I don't think so.  `a  != [a]`.

Comment: hmm.. well it's not raising an error and seems to be working so I think another error is covering for this error! Apparently two wrongs can make a right..lol

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This might due to you are working on a directed network. In directed networks, it is possible to have no neighbors for a non isolated nodes. For example, with 2 nodes a,b and one edge from a to b. Neither a nor b is isolated, a will have neighbor b, but b has no neighbor.

NetworkX defines isolated as no incoming and no outgoing edges but neighbors are not referring the predecessors.

If you apply the np.random.choice on a empty list, you will get the error stated here.

Comment: That was precisely it!!!! Thank you. I couldn't figure out how to code the behavior in there though, so I simply made my network undirected and it solved it. I'll post a solution for a directed network when I do it. Thank you. However, for some reason I still get an exception here and there where the random node picked is not in the graph..which doesn't make sense!!

Comment: Your procedure is not very well defined with directed network. If you only want to allow one directional picking, then you can use len(Neighbs) == 0 to test, but I'm afraid you are trying to generate clusters. Though NetworkX has predecessors() and successors() function for directed networks, it might be better to just use the undirected network since triangles in directed network are tricky.

Comment: Yes that's what I'm doing, but I will have to re-write my code.. eventually to be directed. I didn't know there was a predecessor or successor function - that should help the next time around.

Answer (score 0):

The ValueError you see is coming from `numpy.random.randint` which gives that error when the 'low' and 'high' inputs are not ordered correctly. It is hard to see why you are getting the error. Presumably the `choice` function is calling `randint` with arguments based on features of your input `Neighbs`.

I would start by printing values of Neighbs just before that call and see what you are actually asking it to do.